# Hide download files from SD Card Gallery - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have an app where the user logs in and downloads some images and audio files to their devices SD card.

I don't want these images to be deleted by the user (manually) as this effects how the app is used, so is there anyway to set this folder to private for the sake of the phones gallery?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

Prepend the folder name you create on the sdcard with a "."

so appfiles/

becomes .appfiles/